# How to call the java swing jpanel from another class method in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a Jpanel and I have to call this Jpanel from a class which have the main method. I have called the jpanel method inside my main method. But it not displaying. So how to do it in netbeans?

```
public class A
{

 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here

       B b=new B();
       b.caller();

    }

}
```

Jpanel Class:

```
class B extends Jpanel{


    public void caller()
    {


    initComponents();
    }

  }
```

where init component method is private.So I called this from another method inside the class which is public but nothing working. Help to  solve this in netbeans

Comment: which function you have called ? What do you expect to see ? write a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem

Comment: caller is the function inside the B class. I want the B class Jpanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have called the jpanel method inside my main method. But it not
>   displaying.

[JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) is a generic lightweight container. It cannot be visible by itslef, you need to add it into a `Window` (tipically `JFrame` or `JDialog`) in order to make it visible:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(new B());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

class B extends JPanel {

    public B() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents(){...}
}
```

Take a look to [How to Use Panels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) and [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) tutorials.

Comment: You're welcome! But please spend some time reading the tutorials to understand how Swing works ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this has nothing to do with Netbeans - your question is entirely about how to write operating Swing code.

Second, you haven't given enough information for us to know that you understand how Swing works, so it is difficult to give you correct advice.  A JPanel doesn't display all on its own; it has to go into a container built for displaying on its own -- typically a JFrame.

Your question about calling a JPanel from a different class, even a class that does not itself have (other) references to UI components, can be boiled down to a complete program of no more than 50 lines.  Try writing that, and then ask a question about whatever you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the caller method initializes the jpanel, it should return a JPanel, which you can then add to your JFrame

```
class B extends Jpanel{


    public JPanel caller()  // notice no void, but JPanel
    {


    initComponents();
    }

  }
```

Then inside main

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO code application logic here

   B b=new B();
   myframe.setContentPane(b.caller());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag your japnel class onto jframe (create a new jframe class..name it jpanel_frame)
Then call constructor of jpanel_frame from already existing jframe class from which you want to call jpanel_frame
 .
new jpanel_frame().setVisible(true);