# Calling IntelliJ Swing Forms from another class

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I'm just starting out with Java and I've run into this concept that I don't understand.

I want to know how I can open a form developed with IntelliJ's Swing Form editor from another class. See below this code works fine in one class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUIApp extends JPanel{
    private JButton button1;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private int iCount;


    public GUIApp() {

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                iCount++;
                label1.setText(Integer.toString(iCount));
            }
        });
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUIApp");
    frame.setContentPane(new GUIApp().panel1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

When I try to modify it to create the form from another class with a main method, I run into trouble.

GUIApp.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUIApp extends JPanel{
    private JButton button1;
    private JLabel label1;
    public JPanel panel1;
    private int iCount;


    public GUIApp() {

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                iCount++;
                label1.setText(Integer.toString(iCount));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

App.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUIApp");
                frame.setContentPane(new GUIApp().panel1);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried passing many different things to setContentPane method but nothing has been successful.

The error message I currently gets is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: GUIApp.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:125)
```

Comment: Please check this discussion for some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812806/how-to-call-the-java-swing-jpanel-from-another-class-method-in-netbeans

Comment: If I edit the code for setContentPane to frame.setContentPane(new GUIApp().getter()); and create a new method in the GUIApp class called getter that returns the JPanel. I still get the same error. I really don't understand the issue or why that is different to the responses at the link above.

Comment: Also tried frame.getContentPane().add(new GUIApp()); and frame.getContentPane().add(new GUIApp().getter());

Answer (score 0):

Arghhh... this is an easy one. Surprised no one jumped out and decoded the error message, but I guess I needed to look over it with fresh eyes in the morning for it to come to me.

I think the main issue was that the compiler was trying to run the GUIApp class not the App Class, and was freaking out because I had removed the main class. i.e. I wasn't executing the right class after making the changes.

In the end I used this code:

App.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUIApp");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new GUIApp().getter());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

GUIApp.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUIApp extends JPanel{
    private JButton button1;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private int iCount;

    public GUIApp() {

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                iCount++;
                label1.setText(Integer.toString(iCount));
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel getter(){
        return this.panel1;
    }

}
```